# Why is this error coming in datagrip IDE?

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I have downloaded pgAdmin, made a server, restored the database. Then I connected datagrip IDE with postresql. But then this error is coming
[image: see the error].

Comment: That table or view doesn't exist. Maybe in another schema, but not the one you use right now.

Answer (score 1):

The search path set for the console is `postgres.poublic` (see top-right corner).

The table *film* seems to exist in schema `dvdrental.public` (see the database explorer on the left)

Answer (score 0):

Potential explanations:

- the table has a different name (for example `"Film"`)
- the schema of the table is not on your `search_path`
- the table was created in a different database
- the transaction that created the table never committed